# OpenLDAP Centos 6

Tags: ldap, acl

I am trying to set up some ACLs (starting off with a simple userpassword ACL) on a new OpenLdap deployment.

I am trying to get to grips with the new `conf.d` configuration format - but am struggling.  Can anyone direct me to a good resource for this?  (The obvious resources are yet to be updated to this new way of working it seems)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, the first thing I did with my RHEL6 OpenLDAP installation was to revert back to the legacy slapd.conf file-based configuration, since it's much more amendable to things like version control and Puppet.  However...

If you're familiar with the legacy configuration mechanism, you can set up your ACLs in a slapd.conf file and then use `slaptest` to migrate the configuration to `cn=config` style configuration:

```
# slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d
```

That should give you something to start with.  The online [OpenLDAP documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) already includes lots of documentation about the `cn=config` dynamic configuration mechanism.